# redirecting a java web start app logs to a file

Tags: java, java-web-start

We have an application that we access over Java web start internally at our office.

all the logs produced by the app are displayed in Firefox's console.

what I want to do is to redirect that to a file.

is that possible ?

and how to do that ?

P.S : the application is designed as follow : a client app that accesses an EJB on a server.

the client part is the one made available through java webstart.

Comment: What is used for logging (Log4j, java.util.logging, something else?

Comment: the guys who wrote the app used Log4j in some places but mostly used System.out.println() all over the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured using the System.setOut method could be used to redirect all System.out.println() outputs to a file.

Hence, this could be used in my app :

```
        System.setOut(new PrintStream("C:\\log.txt"));
```