# How do you redirect the console log to a file for Java Web Start in Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, console, logging, java-web-start

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [redirecting a java web start app logs to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472455/redirecting-a-java-web-start-app-logs-to-a-file)

How do you redirect the console log to a file for Java Web Start in Mac OS X? I am running an application as a Java Web Start, and I need the console data to persist; when the app closes, its console goes with it. Is there a way to redirect the console output to a log file?

For now, I am having my application stay open while I debug, but it would be nice to set this up for the unexpected.

Comment: I guess that will work, but not really what I am looking for.

Comment: Since your question is not a duplicate due to being on Mac OS X, you should retag it appropriately, and state it in the wording.

Comment: Changed the tags. Specifically stated under Mac OS X in title and text...not sure where else it should be worded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the answer from [How do I pipe the Java console output to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626389/how-do-i-pipe-the-java-console-output-to-a-file) does work, but the log goes in the following location under OS X (which I have not found documented anywhere):

/~/Library/Caches/Java/log

Comment: Accept your own answer so that it gets marked as solved :D

Comment: Accepting your own answer garners no points, while accepting Kheldar's answer gets you 2.

Comment: Well, I've +1'd him anyway, but I think he should accept his solution as the one containing the answer. Not that I'd ever refuse points, but it's better for users if the answer is marked as such :D

Answer (score 2):

If others happen to get into the problem, I'll let this other interesting bit of information.

The following link has additional information for deployment on OS X: http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/biocore/javawebstart.shtml

and advises to set up in ‘~/.java/.deployment‘ the deployment.properties file with the following entries:

```
 deployment.javaws.showConsole=false  // I changed that to false for your need
 // allow logging to some file
 deployment.javaws.logToFile=true
 // define said file to your heart's desire
 deployment.javaws.logFileName=/tmp/webstart.txt // or ~/toto/whatever.lol if it suits you
```

This way, instead of *~/Library/Caches/Java/log* you get what you wish.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream("log.txt"));
```

and better way is using SL4J ( http://www.slf4j.org/ ) or other logger library.

Comment: Nitpick: SLF4J is a logging facade, not a standalone library.